# Elmah in asp.net mvc release-mode only

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I've installed Elmah (the standard package with default settings) via NuGet manager console.

For a test and better understanding I tried to reconfigure it so it runs in "debug mode" only (after a successful test I'd like to have two different configurations for debug and release e.g. in release send email, in debug not, etc.).

Therefore I've moved most of the (working) configuration from Web.config to **Web.Debug.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
    <errorMail from="XXXX" to="XXXX"
                async="true"  smtpPort="0" />
  </elmah>
  <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Now when I try to open the `elmah.axd` page I get the "The resource cannot be found." error.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

Locally you should use the web.config-file.

The debug or release-mode actually don't have any relation to which config-file is used. It's only when deploying that the transformation takes place:

**web.config**

This is the config file which developers should use locally. Ideally you should get this to be standardized. For instance you could use localhost for DB strings, and what not. You should strive for this to work on dev machines without changes.

**web.debug.config**

This is the transform that is applied when you publish your application to the development staging environment. This would make changes to the web.config which are required for the target environment.

**web.release.config**

This is the transform that is applied when you publish your application to the "production" environment. Obviously you'll have to be careful with passwords depending on your application/team.

Reference link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2010/10/26/asp-net-web-projects-web-debug-config-amp-web-release-config.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So is there any possibility to test the content of web.debug.config or web.release.config without doing a deployment?

Comment: You could deploy to a local environment